# Customizing AxesStyle->Arrowheads

Tags: graphics

How do I call `AxesStyle->Arrowheads[ ]` in order to control whether or not an arrow appears on each of the four ends of the axes in a `Plot`, and if it does appear how to control the size of each one?

Here's an example:

```
Plot[1/x^5, {x, -20, 20}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{-.02, 0}], 
ImagePadding -> None]
```

It seems `Axes->Arrowheads[.05]` makes all 4 of them appear and appear at the same size, while `Axes->Arrowheads[{-.05,.05}]` makes them appear in "pairs". But sometimes I just want the "north" and "west" axes to have arrows and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AxesStyle` takes a list `{x style, y style}` so for "north" and "west" arrows only:

```
Plot[1/x^5, {x, -20, 20}, 
 AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0}], Arrowheads[{0, 0.05}]}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks. I had tried `Arrowheads[{{a,b},{c,d}}]` when I should have been using `Arrowheads[{a,b}],Arrowheads[{b,c}]`